# Do you use past tense to describe an event that happened an hour ago?

Tags: past-tense

I.e. They were serving food, they had chicken wings, chips and etc.

Comment: Definitely. You can even use past tense for 1 second ago. Usually we add "just" so that it emphasizes how recent it happened. "They were serving food, and you just missed it". Just out of curiosity, is there a language you know of that does not use past tense for an hour ago?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You use past tense to talk about actions in the past.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The simple past tense, is used to talk about a completed action in a time before now. Let me repeat it again "before now".
So dude, it can be one second ago, a minute ago, an hour ago etc.

> e.g. A few **minutes** earlier, cousin nick’s bed **collapsed** under his weight.